# WinUsb driver doesn't install

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I'm trying to install the WinUsb driver for one of my device but the installation doesn't succeed and throws away the following error message :

" A problem was encountered while attempting to add the driver to the store"

Any idea what could the problem be ? There is no associated error code or log file and I haven't found any relevant information on the internet about that problem for the WinUsb driver so it's difficult to figure out by my own.

To give you some more context, I'm trying to install it on a Windows 10 machine. On VS 2015, I've created a "WinUsb INF driver install package" and I did some minor modifications to the template INF file provided such as typing in the adequate vid&pid number associated with the device and changing the manufacturer name.

I'm able to successfuly install the driver on a virtual machine running as well Windows10 by right clicking the INF file and selecting "install". (The virtual machine is configured in WDK debugger mode) but the same process on my "real" machine throws the aforementionned error message.

I suspect it has something to do with the signature of the driver but it shouldn't happen as the WinUsb driver is signed (which makes it, inter alia, so interesting to use).

Any hint to solve this issue would be very much appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the INF, you invalidate the signature.  Drivers, INFs, CATs are all linked together.  Modify one and Windows by default won't let you install without disabling driver signature enforcement.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MS website at...

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/fade73e3-a49a-4674-bd36-56586c38cad3/a-problem-was-encountered-while-attempting-to-add-the-driver-to-the-store?forum=wdk

This error message means
**"Your driver package isn't signed or isn't signed correctly."**

*This is a Win OS security feature* to help prevent malware from impersonating a device driver and getting system low level access.

A possible temporary solution to test this theory (and is a **high security risk**) would be to disable the security check. Instructions to do this is located here.

http://jbcomp.com/disable-device-driver-signing-in-windows-10/